# DetachedCriteria - How to convert detached criteria result to integer?

Tags: hibernate, detachedcriteria

Please help me with this.

Im using detached criteria to get the total number of customers.

In my CustomerDaoImpl:

```
@Override
public int getCustomerSize() {
    DetachedCriteria dc = getDetachedCriteria();
    dc.setProjection(Projections.count("customerId"));

    // I need to return only the count result.
    return 0;
}
```

Usually what I do is I get the results, store in a collection and use the `collection.size`. I don't think its efficient for I have to fetch the unnecessary data just to get the `count`. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

```
Number result = (Number) dc.getExecutableCriteria(session).uniqueResult();
return number.intValue();
```